# Webpack dynamic import is overly eager

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm on WebPack 2.2.1

This code

```
let x;
System.import(`./modules/books/${x}.js`);
```

causes WebPack to create split points for all possible values of x.  For example, `modules/books/components/bookSearchModal` and every other file that's a descendant of `modules/books/` is created as a separate split point.

How do I tell WebPack to only create split points for files that sit directly in `modules/books` and not anywhere deeper; in other words, have WebPack assume that `x` will not have any deeper paths.

---

And yes, obviously in reality this code will always have `x` as `undefined`.  This is just meant as a minimal reproduction of my problem.

Comment: That creates a `require.context`. You can get around the issue by setting `require.context` yourself and telling it to avoid recursion (the second parameter should become false).

Comment: Thanks @Juho - is there any kind of example in the docs I could use as a starting point?

Comment: Ah - https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context

Comment: @juho - trying `require.context("./modules/" + x, false, /.js$/)();` but that spits out `58:0-7 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted`

Comment: It probably chokes on that first parameter due to `x`. If you drop that and perform the lookup later, it will likely work.

Comment: @Juho - you mean `let f = require.context("./modules/", false, /.js$/); f(x);` ??

Comment: Yeah. The context looks ok now. Check `.keys()` to see what it matches.

Comment: @juho hm - any way to get it to work with a dynamic *path*? Ie modules/x/x.js?

Comment: I'm missing something obvious here. Did the context miss the files?

Comment: @Juho - just looking for whatever the WebPack way is to create all split points of the form `./modules/${x}/${x}` **without** going recursive.  require.context seemed promising, but it didn't like being set up dynamically, per the error message posted above:  `Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted`

Comment: Is ContextReplacementPlugin what I need, or is there a way to get this automatically?

Comment: `require.context` might not be flexible enough for your needs. It would need a core level change to match your requirement exactly.

Comment: It's that pattern within pattern that's problematic. `require.context` would work better with a single, restricted match. I missed that requirement initially.

Comment: @Juho - hm - I suppose it's easy enough to work around - a simple Node task should be able to spit out some JS code with all possible matches mapped out to all possible `import` calls

Comment: It could become a custom webpack plugin or some such even. Another option would be to use a loader in `require.context` call and do some processing there.